# how to get contents from iframe cross domain

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe

Is there any way to get contents from iframe via php/jQuery or JavaScript? I want to get url when user click on a link in iFrame and its title also.

Comment: you cannot do this, this is a security violation and would get a javascript error when trying. Otherwise anyone could make a fake website with like a bank website set in a full window iframe and grab peoples personal info.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal - why are you using an iframe, what is in the iframe, etc... explain the higher level goal that has lead to you needing this ability

Comment: Any alternative or something through which i can get it?

Comment: user will be provided with some sites, that will load in iframe, just like browser, during navigating in that site, user can add that link to his favorites etc.

Comment: So, your site shows the user some websites - they click one, and it loads up in an iframe on your page - if there's a page within that site that they like, you want them to be able to favourite that link in your system, rather than their browser?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP yes it's the idea. It is because user will create some type of personal notes n dairies from that info

Comment: @TheRaaaZ I would instead look into [creating a bookmarklet](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way/) for the user, and let them visit the website in it's own window/tab rather than an iframe.

Comment: not necessary to open in iframe, if there is any possibility to get link from other browser tab or window but not manually, then it will be OK

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

From arbitrary URLs? No.

From URLs you control? Yes, in modern browsers.

The document being clicked in should use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) to send whatever data you are interested in to the other document which needs to listen for a message event.

```
top.postMessage({ url: location.href }, "*");
```

and

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
function receiveMessage(evt) {
    alert(event.data.url);
}
```

Comment: The question is whether the URLs are to sites that you manage, or if they're outside of your control.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this because of the potential security issues.

I would instead suggest finding another way of allowing users to send data to your website from somewhere else, such as the use of a bookmarklet.

A bookmarklet is basically a snippet of javascript that can be saved as a bookmark in their browser - they can then click that bookmark on the other website to run your code (which does whatever).

[Creating a bookmarklet](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way/)