# How to get an element outside of iframe with javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to get a element from outside of iframe with js or jQuery. I found something but it's not cross browser.

```
<div id=vi-desc-maincntr"">
    <div class="u-flL iti-act-num">123456789</div>
    <div id="desc_div">
        <iframe src="LOCATION">
    </div>
</div>
```

I need that number into a variable.

Comment: Are the iframes in the same [sub]domain?

Comment: nope. it's the iframe for description in ebay

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356533/how-to-get-contents-from-iframe-cross-domain

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Same-origin policy**:
 You might want to check this. Two pages need to have the same origin.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

---

If your child page is located at same domain as parent page, You can write a code like below in the child window :

```
 $('#test1', parent.document).html('<h1>clicked</h1>');
```

The second parameter provides the `context` in which to search the element matched by the first parameter. The Document is here:http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context

```
 jQuery( selector [, context ] )
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it's not same domain, first is ebay.co.uk and iframe is http://vi.vipr.ebaydesc.com/

Comment: Then you can't do it. Click on the link in his answer, please.